# How do I detect when it comes to the end in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm filing my data with json to recyclerview.
I want new data in every 10 items in recyclerview.

> So
>   **10 data -> arrived 10 more data in recyclerview last** ....

**So how do I detect that the user is at the end of the recyclerview?**
Or, if there is another solution, you can submit your ideas. I use it for now, but sometimes it doesn't work ...

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
               // MyLog.log("rcv1 " + newState);


            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                MyLog.log("rcv1 dy: "+ dy);
                if (dy>=0 ){
                    llHeading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    llHeading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loadingItems && (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount ) {
                    loadingItems = true;
                    MyLog.log("rcv1 came to an end.");

                    getDataClient("",rccount*10,ranking_sort_by,ranking_desc,1);


                }

            }


        });
```

Comment: Looks like you want to implement pagination for your recycler view. Have you tried using Paging library https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging ?

Comment: I've never seen this before it really works. Thanks @Dmitrii Leonov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your adapter, you could use `onBindViewHolder` then check the position.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        // You are at the end of list
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same. I think this is the default method to do it: load more items as soon as the last item is being created. It's easy and straightforward, and you don't need to deal with scroll listeners

Comment: Thank u bro :) i solved problem. I'm questioning why I don't use onbindviewholder right now. I didn't think :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```java
  recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Log.d("tag","scrolled to end");

            }
        }
    });
```